# Mathematica simulation random simulation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to simulate  mutation of two parts a and b in Mathematica.
I put in the genetic drift (totally random element) by:

```
p[sim_, 0] = Join[Table[a, {15}], Table[b, {15}]]
p[sim_, t_] := p[sim, t] = RandomChoice[p[sim, t - 1], 30]
```

This created two tables with randomly composed of parts a and b.

I want to add in mutation, occurring with a given probability,  so I've tried appending the following onto my code above

```
Do[ReplacePart[p, i -> b] && If[RandomReal[] > .2, t], {t, 1, 15}]
```

So it ought to replace an element i of the original two tables if a randomly drawn number between 0 and 1 is greater than .2.

So my final code looks like

```
p[sim_, 0] = Join[Table[a, {15}], Table[b, {15}]]
p[sim_, t_] := p[sim, t] = RandomChoice[p[sim, t - 1], 30];
Do[If[RandomReal[] < .2, 
  ReplacePart[p[sim, t], {_} -> RandomChoice[{a, b}]], 
  p[sim, t]], {t, 1, 15}]
```

But I can tell its not working as changing the value RandomReal has to be greater than is not doing anything, but I'm not getting an error message.

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is your only problem, but ReplacePart operates on the result returned by P[], but does not affect the function itself,
ie.

```
f[0]={1,2,3}
ReplacePart[f[0],2->42] -> {1,42,3}
```

but you still get:

```
f[0] -> {1,2,3}
```

Also

```
{_} ->
```

tells ReplacePart to replace every item.  I'm not sure what your intent is there...
the first incarnation `i->` seems to make sense..

Comment: Ah yes I want it to operate on the result returned by P, so P returns a list of 30 items, a or b, then I want ReplacePart to change one of the values if the randomly drawn integer is above 0.1, iterated as P also works. I tried both _ and i but neither would work.

Comment: well after the replacement you dont do anything with it so you really can't tell if it is working or not. Your loop only returns the value from the last pass.  You could wrap ReplacePart[] in Print[] if you just want to see it.

Comment: this may be what you want: ReplacePart[ p[sim, t],   RandomInteger[{1, 30}] -> RandomChoice[{a, b}]], but again if you dont do something with the result itis just discarded.